# Can I use the Wordpress API to push and pull data from other websites?

Tags: wordpress, rest, api, content-management-system

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Wordpress RESTful API to push and pull data and information from/to other websites.

For example, could I make my own application/website, like a CMS, that would utilize the WP API to change content, images, etc on other websites? And if so, what would the basic process of setting that up look like?

New to this, so sorry for not being more specific!

Comment: REST does not allow for push updates, but you could use a polling query to pull updates or switch to using something that is subscription based like GraphQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Answer is "Yes, Its possible"

The WordPress REST API provides API endpoints for WordPress data types that allow developers to interact with sites remotely by sending and receiving JSON objects. When you send content to or make a request to the API, the response will be returned in JSON. This enables developers to create, read and update WordPress content from client-side JavaScript or from external applications, even those written in languages beyond PHP.

Please check wordpress codex for more information.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. Is it possible for the created app to have access to several different wordpress sites? Or would you begin to run into authentication issues?